# Finding item in list with string name ending in largest number?

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I have a list of blob names that end with a number, i.e. "blob_0", "blob_1", "blob_2"

I want to find the name that ends in the largest number. I.e., in the above case, blob_2. Here's the code I have now:

```
     private string GetTailEndBlob(List<string> blobNames, CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        List<int> blobNumbers = blobNames.ConvertAll(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)));
        var maxBlobNumber = blobNumbers.Max();
        var maxBlobName = blobNames.Where(x => x.Contains("_" + maxBlobNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
        var blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(maxBlobName);
```

This seems like a lot of work for basically some string manipulation. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just

```
string maxBlobName = blobNames.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)))
                              .First();
```

That way you're only iterating the collection once instead of three times.

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks!